# Excel 2007 on Win 7 Home Edition -- failure to sum numbers when pasted from other source

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I copied/pasted columns of numbers from my bank statements into Excel.  When I try to sum groups of numbers, it does not sum them.  Matter of fact, when I select a group of cells with numbers, it does not show the totals *dynamically* at the bottom like it normally does.

Now, if I enter the same values from the keyboard, and select a group of those numbers, the dynamic tally at the bottom works, as does any `=sum()` entry.

I've tried using `General`, `Number`, `Accounting`, and `Currency` to format the entire column, and it makes no difference.  I confirmed I have `Formulas > Calculation Options > Automatic` set correctly, and that there are no `Circular Reference` errors in my column of numbers.

I added the `DigDB` Add-in, and it didn't do anything much when I ran the `Convert` to make sure the numbers were `Numbers`.

I've seen this before when I cut and pasted from another data source, and have no idea still what the cause nor the cure can be.

Ideas??

Comment: What decimal place character is your system/Excel set to? If Excel expects `.` but you're banking numbers use `,` (or vice-versa), Excel will treat those numbers as text no matter what number format you choose.

Comment: Also try using VALUE function to convert numeric text to Number format. You may however have to run this function in some adjacent blank column and if it successfully converts into Number format, then sum it up on that column.

Comment: Yes, the banking data has commas for values > 999.99, but is also uses the decimal for cents.  I have Excel set to define the columns I'm importing  INTO as Numbers, 2 decimals places, and "use commas".  I tried the VALUE function, and it didn't convert the source cells correctly (gave me the "VALUE!" error).  Something is fishy with the internal representation of the data I've copied into the cells.  LOOKS like a number, but is not somehow.  I'm continuing to troubleshoot....thanks very much for your suggestions!

Comment: are there any leading or trailing spaces in the data in original column? Just to eliminate the possibility trim it using TRIM function. You could also try =VALUE(TRIM(A1))   for example.